# Using Intentdefinition Compiler using cmake for code generation

Tags: xcode, cmake

In Xcode, when we create an intent definition file, a corresponding swift file gets generated for the intent defined in the intent definition file. This happens with the help of IntentDefinition Compiler , which can be seen in the build settings of a native xcode project.

[image]

I am generating an xcode project using cmake and I have an Intent definition file for which I need the generated swift code. But I m not aware of how to specify this Intent Definition Compiler for swift or Is this even available feature using cmake. Can someone help on how to add this to my generated Xcode project using cmake, so that the required intent handling code can be generated?

Comment: meta note: cross posted on CMake discourse https://discourse.cmake.org/t/using-intentdefinition-compiler-using-cmake-for-code-generation/10229